# apply linear model to nested data

Tags: r

I wanted to apply a linear model to nested data set in R . I am facing a error in my code and i am not able to figure it out.

```
country_model <- function(df) {
  lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df)
}

apminder.model  <- gapminder.nested %>% 
 mutate(model = map(data, country_model), 
        coef = map(model, broom::tidy))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'.

Comment: Try with `model = map(data, ~ country_model)`. Could you also provide a reproducible example?

Comment: gapminder.model  <- gapminder.nested %>% 
+     mutate(model = map(data,~country_model), 
+            coef = map(model, broom::tidy))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: no recognized region names.SRY a new error popped out

Comment: This works like a charm `country_model <- function(df) {
  lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = df)
};iris %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  nest(-Species) %>% 
  mutate(model=map(data, country_model),
         coef = map(model, broom::tidy))` So your `gapminder.nested` could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

@ANG's comment has the correct solution, a tilde was missing in front of the function:

```
model = map(data, ~ country_model)
```

The new error you encountered

```
## Evaluation error: no recognized region names
```

was because you loaded the `maps` package after `purrr` and the `map` function was masked. Easy solution is to use `purrr::map` instead of just `map`.